# Angular - primeng dialog with tab view having simple bootstrap forms not getting autofocus to each tab form

Tags: angular, primeng

We have a primeng dialog with multiple tabs displaying forms respectively. Default first tab gets opened and as we click rest tabs , respective form gets opened.
In general what are valid ways to show autofocus to form first field , as tabs already loaded and we are switching between tab forms ?

```
<p-tabView>
    <p-tabPanel>Form1</p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel>Form2</p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel>Form3</p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

Comment: Let me understand, do you want to focus on form's first field whenever tabPanel changed right ?

Comment: When ever form get opened , either from landing on dialog screen Or
switching from tabs
autofocus should be visible to first field.

Comment: You can make use of `onChange` event, this event occur when tab is changed, so when tab changed focus on the first field [Read more](https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/tabview)

Comment: onChange - understood. But Angular form itself has autofocus issue. It does not work with just  HTML style appending autofocus attribute/ tabindex. so we tried a way but its using viewChild event emitter style and thats lengthy code

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the input element a template reference variable #myInput:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="title" #form1Input />
```

Let your component implement AfterViewInit, grab the reference of the input element with the ViewChild annotation and focus your element in the ngAfterViewInit hook:

```
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {

        @ViewChild("form1Input") private formOneInputElement: ElementRef;
        @ViewChild("form2Input") private formTwoInputElement: ElementRef;
        @ViewChild("form3Input") private formThreeInputElement: ElementRef;

        [...]

        onTabChange(event: Event): void {

            switch(event.index) {

                case 0 : {

                    this.formOneInputElement.nativeElement.focus();
                    break;
                }   

                case 1 : {

                    this.formTwoInputElement.nativeElement.focus();
                    break;
                }

                case 2: {

                    this.formThreeInputElement.nativeElement.focus();   
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: tab change :  (* onChange  event) how #myInput will get back focus ?

Comment: Yeah you can use `event.index` for check which tab got selected and based on that index, you can set focus by using  `this._inputElement.nativeElement.focus();`

Comment: Refer this https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabview-with-form-focus